# c# adding a string to an array

Tags: c#, arrays

i want to simply add a string to an array, like this:

```
string[] arrayName = new string[0];
        arrayName.Add("raptor");
```

But this doesn't work, can someone help me?

Comment: Copying your question title into google produces [numerous results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+adding+a+string+to+an+array&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=G-aMVoH9NYHJaOu3oeAB)... have you tried any of them?

Comment: arrays are immutable. when you create array of size 0 you cant change it. the only way is to recreate a new array with bigger size. (which list does)

Comment: Another way to do this (although I *definitely* recommend the use of generic collections) would be to resize your array, that's if you wanted to stick with arrays. `Array.Resize(ref arrayName, 1); arrayName[0] = "raptor";` You could wrap that up in your own `Add` method if you must.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a generic [List(Of T)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
myStrings.Add("raptor");
```

and if you really want an array:

```
string[] myStringArray = myStrings.ToArray();
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the fast reaction. But what is the difference between an array and a list?

Comment: @BvdL Generally speaking, a list is a collection that you can easily add/remove items to/from. An array usually has a fixed size, which is not that convenient to modify.